# Professional architecture to handle a 500GB MongoDb database

Tags: mongodb, database-design, database

We have a large database and I would like to explain how basic we have set it up. So, **I would like to know what was your architecture if you were instead of us**.

1. 560GB is the total size of /data/ folder of MongoDb (So the pure data size is much lower)
2. Database server and Web server are hosted on a single dedicated server
3. No SSD is present
4. OS is Windows Server 2012
5. MongoDb is running as a single instance, simply as an EXE file
6. As an estimate, on average there are about 50 findAndModify, 20 INSERT, and 10 GET queries PER MINUTE
7. Some INSERTs are including large documents about 1MB
8. There are 2600 collections in the database
9. Some collections will be used for storing large documents - size veries between 10kb to 600kb - in rare cases a much higher
10. Indexing is available on two string keys
11. CPU usage is about 6% and RAM is almost free. 16GB total ram and 4GB used

Now we have faced with some problems particularly regarding the I/O speed. Insert performance is satisfying, however update and querying performance is poor. Some queries will be made on a collection with 3M documents which explains why it is poor.

So we are looking for a work around. What is your suggestion, and let us know what is a more efficient architecture. Please consider the budget in your suggestions. We all know that 10 separate SSD servers would be a great solution.
Our current options are:

1. Add a second SSD HDD
2. Add a cluster linux dedicated server for database - spinning disk HDD
3. Sharding database with a VPS
4. LET US KNOW OTHER OPTIONS

Any suggestions, our mistakes reminders and tips would be great.

========================

**Answer?**

Indexing! A mistake in indexing was the key problem. We have revised all our indexing keys and everything solved. Now RAM is used 100%, and the performance is excellent. We hear the indexing and we say it is ok! however, more attention is required.

Comment: This is not a well-stated question.  Do you have a specific problem?  Is there a particular query which is slow?  How slow is it?  Do you have an index on that query?

Comment: @skelly I would like to know is this architecture acceptable in your point of view? Is in fine or you see problems in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used MongoDB on Windows, but two things I would change:

- MongoDB loves SSD's. Move your data to one
- Consider splitting web and MongoDB to two servers

Only 4GB of RAM used would be strange on a Linux system, but I don't know about Windows.

I don't think sharding would be a good idea and it would be a bit complicated with your 2600 collections in the same database. A replica set could be a solution if you were to run your reads on it.

Another option would be to split the 2600 collections into multiple databases to get a write lock for each database.